# How use openssl to verify a certificate in PEM with a local trust store?

Tags: c, openssl, certificate, x509certificate, x509

I have a certificate in PEM format. Let say I have a certificate that I copied from google.com.

So, the chain is that

Google Trust Services-GlobalSign Root CA-R2

->Google Internet Authority G3

-->*.google.com

Suppose that I have certificate `*.google.com` and I want a C program to verify this certificate with my local trust store in Linux. Let say `/etc/ssl/certs`.

I need to it offline without connecting to the server. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

The overall OpenSSL documentation around this topic is rather limited and has broken links all over the place, so my approach might not the only one or best one. As far as I can see, verifying a certificate (chain) is done with the following steps, unrolled in reverse order because I think that gives a better understanding. For the resulting code, see the end of this answer. All code has error checking omitted for the sake of brevity. Also, the loading of Certificate Revocation Lists (CRLs) is not explained, I think that is beyond the scope of your question.

**The actual verification function**

The functionality to verify a certificate (chain) is provided by the OpenSSL function [X509_verify_cert()](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/X509_verify_cert.html). A return value of `1` indicates successful verification, `0` indicates no success. As you can see in the documentation, the function only requires one parameter of the type `X509_STORE_CTX`, which is a structure holding the "context" (a rather vague and overused term in OpenSSL, IMO) of the collection of `X509` certificates involved.

**Setting up the certificate store context**

The certificate store context contains information about trusted certificates, untrusted intermediate certificates and the certificate to be verified. It is constructed and initialized as follows:

```
store_ctx = X509_STORE_CTX_new();
X509_STORE_CTX_init(store_ctx, store, cert, intermediates)
```

The `store` parameter will be used to contain information about the trusted certificates, the `cert` parameter contains the certificate to be verified and the and `intermediates` parameter is a stack of untrusted intermediate certificates.

**The `store` parameter**

The `X509_STORE` type is able a contain a set of X509 certificates and for the purpose of verifying a certificate needs to be provided with information about trusted certificates. Since you indicated that you have trusted certificates in `/etc/ssl/certs`, this can be done as follows:

```
store = X509_STORE_new();
lookup = X509_STORE_add_lookup(store, X509_LOOKUP_hash_dir());
X509_LOOKUP_add_dir(lookup, "/etc/ssl/certs", X509_FILETYPE_PEM);
```

This assumes that your local trust store is set up properly

**The `cert` parameter`**

This parameter contains the actual certificate to be verified. It can be loaded from a file in several ways, one approach is as follows:

```
bio_in = BIO_new_file(certFileName, "r");
result = PEM_read_bio_X509(bio_in, NULL, NULL, NULL);
BIO_free(bio_in);
```

**The `intermediates` parameter**

OpenSSL provides a [stack API](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/STACK_API) to handle collections of objects. The `intermediates` parameter is a stack of `X509` objects that contains the intermediate certificates between your certificate to be tested and your trusted certificate. In pseudo code, it can be filled as follows:

```
intermediates = sk_X509_new_null();
for (filename in certFilenames) do {
    icert = readCert(filename);
    sk_X509_push(intermediates, icert);
}
```

This concludes the explanation, this should give you all you need to verify the chain.

**About the certificate at the end of the downloaded chain

The certificate at the end of the downloaded chain is typically contained in your local trust store. Some experiments show that you can actually feed it into the verify function as if it is an untrusted intermediate or you can omit it. Both seemed to end in a properly verified chain.

**A code example**

Finally :-)

```
#include <openssl/x509.h>
#include <openssl/x509_vfy.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>

const char *trustedCertsPath = "/etc/ssl/certs";

int main(
    int argc,
    char **argv)
{
    X509 *cert = NULL;
    X509 *icert = NULL;
    STACK_OF(X509) *intermediates = NULL;
    X509_STORE *store = NULL;
    X509_LOOKUP *lookup = NULL;
    X509_STORE_CTX *store_ctx = NULL;
    BIO *bio_in = NULL;
    int currentArg = 1;
    int result = 0;

    store = X509_STORE_new();
    lookup = X509_STORE_add_lookup(store, X509_LOOKUP_hash_dir());
    X509_LOOKUP_add_dir(lookup, trustedCertsPath, X509_FILETYPE_PEM);

    /* Certificate to be checked */
    bio_in = BIO_new_file(argv[currentArg++], "r");
    cert = PEM_read_bio_X509(bio_in, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    BIO_free(bio_in);

    /* Stack of untrusted intermediate certificates */
    intermediates = sk_X509_new_null();
    while (currentArg < argc) {
        bio_in = BIO_new_file(argv[currentArg++], "r");
        icert = PEM_read_bio_X509(bio_in, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        BIO_free(bio_in);
        sk_X509_push(intermediates, icert);
    }

    store_ctx = X509_STORE_CTX_new();
    X509_STORE_CTX_init(store_ctx, store, cert, intermediates);

    result = X509_verify_cert(store_ctx);
    printf("Result from X509_verify_cert is %d\n", result);

    sk_X509_pop_free(intermediates, X509_free);
    X509_STORE_CTX_cleanup(store_ctx);
    X509_STORE_CTX_free(store_ctx);
    X509_STORE_free(store);
}
```

You can build and run it as follows (where the `.pem` arguments are the names of the files containing your certificate and intermediates in PEM format:

```
$ gcc  main.c $(pkg-config openssl --libs) -o verify -Wall
$ ./verify \*.google.com.pem Google\ Internet\ Authority\ G3.pem
Result from X509_verify_cert is 1
```